# CakePHP: $validate and jQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm creating `<input>` tags with jQuery dynamically, but the `$validate` rules I set don't seem to work, what is wrong?

```
// The inputs for this model are created dynamically
class OrderProducts extends AppModel {

public $validate = array(
    'quantity' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    ),
    'price' => array(

        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    )
);
}
```

Normally I just do `$this->Form->input('fieldName')` and `CakePHP` validates it with the `$validate` property.

Comment: We're not mind-readers. Show some code.

Comment: @FDL if we assume that validation works with static inputs, then the question is quite obvious.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am dynamically creating an <input> (using jquery), and I want the cakePHP's Model validation to work cause it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public $validate = array(
        'quantity' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'This field is required',
                'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
            'price' => array(
                'notempty' => array(
                   'rule' => array('notempty'),
                   'message' => 'This field is required',
                   'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
));
```

read this plz [Cakephp validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html)

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what I am doing. And it works for <inputs> that are printed using the FormHelper. The thing is that if I dynamically create an <input> with the correct name tag (example: name=Data[Model][field]) the validation doesn't seem to work